# how to switch values between tow columns using one select query in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

This represents exchanges table between pairs where Bob is involved :

```
     Pair1      pair2        exchanges  
     Bob        Alice        12
     Jack       Bob          6  
     Max        Bob          22
     Bob        Steve        100
```

the idea is to make Bob appear only at pair1 or pair2 using a select query, the output should looks like the following:

```
     Pair1      pair2        exchanges
     Bob        Alice        12
     Bob        Jack          6  
     Bob        Max          22
     Bob        Steve        100
```

Comment: Go on. Try something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GMB's answer is probably more performant.  From a logic perspective, though, I am thinking:

```
select pair1, pair2, exchanges
from t
where pair1 = 'Bob'
union all
select pair2, pair1, exchanges
from t
where pair2 = 'Bob'
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want :

```
SELECT
    'Bob' AS pair1,
    CASE 
        WHEN pair1 = 'Bob' THEN pair2
        ELSE pair1
    END AS pair2,
    exchanges
FROM mytable
WHERE pair1 = 'Bob' OR pair2 = 'Bob'
```

The query uses a CASE construct to select the revelvant column.